# How do I placed multiple markers on react-native map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, react-native

Hi just learn to use react-native and javascript. How do I placed multiple markers on react-native map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just push more data into the marker and setstate to marker and assign to

```
annotations={this.state.marker}

var tempMarker = [];
for (var p in responseData) {
    tempMarker.push({
        latitude: region.latitude,
        longitude: region.longitude
    })
}

this.setState({
    marker: tempMarker
})
```

Comment: Can You Explain How it is Use Step by Step Procedure...?